# Updating(involving values of a dictionary in math operations) values in a dictionary -- Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm working on a database for a fictional basketball league for 2 teams in total. i created a dictionary to store the total points scored in the season, using the team names as the keys in the dictionary. problem is, i'm trying to update those values for every game played. For example if Team1 scored 80 points in a game, the total points is  80, if they scored 40 points in the next game, the total points should be 120 in the dictionary. how can i accomplish this exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
team1 = {
    'score': 0
    }

team1['score'] += 80
team1['score'] += 40
```

Below is the REPL flow

```
>>> team1 = {
    'score': 0
}

>>> team1['score'] += 80
>>> team1
    {'score': 80}
>>> team1['score'] += 40
>>> team1
    {'score': 120}
```